# Using 'Contains' on an Array

Tags: arrays, vb6

Ok, so I'm not very familiar with VB6 but I'm trying to see if an array contains a value. This is what I have but it's throwing up an error to me. Could be an issue with the "passedValue" being the wrong type but I don't think so.

```
    Dim transCodes As Variant
    transCodes = Array(40, 41, 42, 43)
    If (transCodes.Contains("passedValue")) Then
    *Do Stuff*
    End If
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Failing correcting my syntax, could you give me an example for the cast/convert I might use to ensure the "passedValue" was of the right type?

**UPDATING MY UPDATE**

So is there no 'Contains' method in VB6? Any other ways of doing this simple task?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

VB6 doesn't have a native `Contains` method on arrays.

Your best option is to walk the array checking each item in turn:

```
Found = False
For Index = LBound(transCodes) To UBound(transCodes )
  If transCodes(Index) = PassedValue Then
    Found = True
    Exit For
  End If
Next

If Found Then
  'Do stuff
  'Index will contain the location it was found
End If
```

Alternatives include using a collection and trying to retreive items based on their value, but this is much more work for this simple case.

Comment: Sigh, wow VB6 really is legacy when it can't even do simple things like this. I'm used to C#. Will try and just walk through it now.

Comment: Note that if your array is in order (as your example is) you can optimize this to perform a binary search instead of walking the entire array. This will give you much better performance if you have a massive array.

Comment: @Deanna Hmm I think I'm still getting a parse issue. Could you show me how to convert PassedValue into the correct type also?

Comment: I'd assumed they were both the same types. If they're numbers, there shouldn't be a problem. If one is a string, then pass it to `Val()` first. What exact problem are you having?

Comment: @Deanna I would prefer `CInt()` to `Val()` (or the corresponding `C__()` function.)

Comment: Ah, (bad) habit, I tend to rely on silent 0 conversion

Answer (score 4):

If you want this in just one line, you can check whether a string array contains an item (without a loop) with the following code:

```
' ARR is an array of string, SEARCH is the value to be searched
Found = InStr(1, vbNullChar & Join(arr, vbNullChar) & vbNullChar, _
vbNullChar & search & vbNullChar) > 0
```

This was taken from a [Devx tip](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18364)

Comment: I only must change vbNullChar by " ". With vbNullChar don´t worked for me

Comment: That is suitably horrible! I'm impressed :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped Deanna's answer as a VB6 function:

```
Public Function StringArrayContains(ByRef arrString() As Boolean, PassedValue) As String
   Dim Found As Boolean
   Found = False
   Dim index  As Integer
    For Index = LBound(arrString) To UBound(arrString)
      If arrString(Index) = PassedValue Then
        Found = True
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
    StringArrayContains = Found
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally based on @Mostafa Anssary

I used this function

```
    Function instrSplit(ByVal searchEstado As String, ByVal arrayEstados As String)

       instrSplit = 0

       instrSplit = InStr(1, " " & Join(Split(arrayEstados, ","), " ") & " ", _
                " " & searchEstado & " ")

    End Function
```

And I Call by

```
found = instrSplit(mySearchValue, arrayValues)
```

For example

```
arrayValues = "8, 64, 72, 1520"
mySearchValue  = "8"


found = instrSplit(mySearchValue, arrayValues)
```